# Why the questionmark in sqlite3 doesn't work?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I'm trying to use sqlite3 from python. In the official documentation (https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) it is written you shouldn't use string operation for the building of queries because very breakable. Instead you should use the question mark as placeholder:

```
# Never do this -- insecure!
symbol = 'RHAT'
c.execute("SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol = '%s'" % symbol)

# Do this instead
t = ('RHAT',)
c.execute('SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol=?', t)
print c.fetchone()
```

My syntax is extremely easy but I don't know why it doesn't work:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('../Downloads/chinook.db')
c = conn.cursor()

t = ('trackid',)
c.execute('select ? from tracks',t)
for i in c:
    print (i)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

in this way it prints just the string "('trackid',)" as many times as it occurs in the table while writing in this way:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('../Downloads/chinook.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('select trackid from tracks')
for i in c:
    print (i)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

works perfectly fine. What am I missing?

Comment: You can't pass a column name as a parameter. For this, you need string concatenation.

Comment: things like [`psycopg2.extensions.AsIs`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.AsIs) can help if you truly want to do columns as parameters although you should construct column names yourself since this is usually not given as user input, which is what parameter substitution guards against

Comment: In general you cannot parameterise database identifiers (tables, columns, views, etc) - only values.

Answer (score 3):

The question mark isn't meant to stand in for a column name; it's meant to stand in for a column's *value*.  This is true of all RDBMS's.

So while this won't work:

```
c.execute('select ? from tracks',t)
```

This will.

```
c.execute('select * from tracks where trackid = ?',t)
```

The admonition against string concatenation is meant to protect against [sql injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) attacks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind object names (in this case - a column name) like that, only values. The string you're binding is interpreted as a string literal.

For such usecases, you'll indeed have to resort to string manipulation:

```py
t = 'trackid'
c.execute('select %s from tracks' % t)
```

Comment: while this may be work, it is not recommended since this is prone to SQL injection. For examle, an adversary could pass in an input like `* from admin--` . And if an Admin table do exist, it will return the rows for admin table

Comment: @velociraptor11 How do you do it then?